# Getting a property in a user control to set content of a label inside the user control

Tags: wpf

I have created a user control [(link)](https://stackoverflow.com/q/11089895/721768) which has a label and a button.

I would like for the control to have a property called `Text` which sets the content of the label.

In XAML

```
<my:SomeUserControl Text="Hello" />
```

which actually sets the

```
<Label Content="Hello">
```

in my user control.

How can I create this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

make da [dependency property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.dependencyproperty.aspx) in your user control. Give your user control in the xaml a name, like

```
<UserControl x:Name="myUserControl"
```

and bind it inside your xaml like this.

```
<Label Content="{Binding ElementName=myUserControl, Path=Text}">
```

Comment: Cool. What does the "ElementName=myUserControl" do?

Comment: Binding usually binds the DataContexts Path property. DataContext is set on the control or inherited through the parents. You have different ways to modify the "Source" from where the Path should be used for your binding. ElementName directly uses the control with that name found in the current namescope. Other options are RelativeSource, which traverses the visual tree upwards until a specific condition is met; or Source, where you could set a static class for example.

Comment: Can you recommend a book or article that explains similar stuff?